# Updating component props value on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Lets say I have variable call myvariable and I want to update the value from 1# boolean to 2# object

```
export class controller extends component {

  1# let myvariable = true;

   
  2# click event would update this.myvariable = { dataNew = 20 }


  3# dataView: myvariable ;

}
```

On 2# I want to update myvariable to an object with value dataNew = 20, will my component understand an update 3# dataView to new value on realtime?

Comment: why don't you try it and find out? what you have written doesn't look like javascript or angular, so it's hard to tell what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's doable although it's not recommended.

Assign myvariable to type any.

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  myvariable: any = true;

  update() {
    this.myvariable = {dataNew: 20};
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-spsiuq